# Squid proxy docker container stops working without restart

Tags: docker, ubuntu, squid

I am running Squid proxy on a docker container. I am accessing this proxy server from another computer to connect to the internet.
The setup works fine, but when I reboot the host machine(ubuntu 23.04) I need to **manually stop and start** the squid's docker container as well. Not sure why I need to do that.

I checked the access logs and see that squid is not getting the request after I reboot the host machine. Once I stop and start the squid container, everything works fine.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install squid -y
ADD squid.conf /etc/squid/
ENTRYPOINT service squid start  && sleep infinity
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  fwdproxy:
    container_name: squid
    build:
      context: build
    image: squid #for tagging
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${FORWARD_PROXY_PORT}:3128
    mem_limit: ${DEFAULT_MEMORY_LIMIT}
    cpus: ${DEFAULT_CPU_LIMIT}
    volumes:
      - /var/log/squid:/var/log/squid
```

I remember I was not having this issue when using tinyproxy. But I faced another issue using it. Thats a thread for another day.